# A cubic equation: $u^3−2u^2−2v^3−20v^2+16v=0$

Tags: elliptic-curves, cubics

**Update (Dec. 22):** I have already solved this question with *Magma*.

Recently, I read a paper [1] and saw the following equation:
$$u^3−2u^2−2v^3−20v^2+16v=0.$$
The author then got a Weierstrass equation
$$Y^2=X^3-X^2-41X+441$$
through such transformation:
$$X=\dfrac{-4u-3v+8}{v},$$
$$Y=-2\left(\dfrac{-u^3+4u^2-4u+2v^3+10v^2}{v^2}\right).$$
I know Nagell's algorithm (see, e.g., [2]) is a good approach to deal with such equation. But when I tried to transform it through Nagell's algorithm, I got a weird equation with large coefficients. My question is: *how did the author get the transformation? Are there any tricks?*

[1] P. Ingram, On kth-power numerical centers, *C. R. Math. Acad. Sci. R. Can.*, **27** (2005), 105--110.

[2]  R. J. Stroeker and B. M. M. de Weger, Solving elliptic Diophantine equations: the general cubic case, *Acta Arith.*, **87** (1999), 339--365.

Comment: What did you get with Nagell? Undoubtedly you noticed that the r.h.s. cubic is not of the familiar $X^3+aX+b$ form. I'm not an expert, but this suggests to me that the form you got may be correct, but not in the minimal Weierstrass form. IIRC an algorithm for finding the minimal Weierstrass form is described in one of Silverman's books.

Comment: I got $y^2=x^3-160x^2-2048x+2162688$ after following steps listed in [2]. Then I tried to substitute $X$ and $Y$ given by the author back to his Weierstrass form, and the equation I got was far different to the original one. Now I have no idea.

Comment: If you substitute $x=16X$ and $y=64yY$ in your equation, you get 
$$Y^2=X^3-10X^2-8X+528.$$ Both this equation and the equation
$Y^2=X^3-X^2-41X-441$ have discriminants $-2^{13}\cdot3\cdot5^2\cdot11^2$, which is too much of a coincidence. Further minimizing may thus be possible at $p=2$. Trying to recall how that is done :-)

Comment: As a way of confirmation. Both curves have $j$-invariant equal to
$$j=-953312/9075.$$ Thus we can get one from the other. Hang in there!!!

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/44610/11619).

Comment: An algorithm for finding the minimal Weierstrass form is described [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1982-38-157/S0025-5718-1982-0637305-2/S0025-5718-1982-0637305-2.pdf). See [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10607/writing-down-minimal-weierstrass-equations). I was doing some trial-and-error fumbling, but couldn't get to the minimal 2-adic model :-( May be PARI/GAP has this implemented?

Comment: Sorry that I did not update my question. Days ago I have noticed it. Also I found MAGMA a fantastic software to deal with such question. Thank you for your help!